# Использование памяти и ресурсов процессора для определенного процесса

Tags: linux

Мне необходимо узнать, сколько памяти и сколько ресурсов процессора потребляет определенный процесс. Если быть точнее, мне нужна информация о том, в каком файле и в какой строке лежит данная информация.

Единственное, что я знаю — это то, что файл расположен в папке `/proc` в подпапке, имя которой равно ID этого процесса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

из [документации](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt):

```
Table 1-1: Process specific entries in /proc
..............................................................................
 File       Content
 clear_refs Clears page referenced bits shown in smaps output
 cmdline    Command line arguments
 cpu        Current and last cpu in which it was executed   (2.4)(smp)
 cwd        Link to the current working directory
 environ    Values of environment variables
 exe        Link to the executable of this process
 fd     Directory, which contains all file descriptors
 maps       Memory maps to executables and library files    (2.4)
 mem        Memory held by this process
 root       Link to the root directory of this process
 stat       Process status
 statm      Process memory status information
 status     Process status in human readable form
 wchan      Present with CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y: it shows the kernel function
        symbol the task is blocked in - or "0" if not blocked.
 pagemap    Page table
 stack      Report full stack trace, enable via CONFIG_STACKTRACE
 smaps      a extension based on maps, showing the memory consumption of
        each mapping and flags associated with it
 numa_maps  an extension based on maps, showing the memory locality and
        binding policy as well as mem usage (in pages) of each mapping.
```

например, для получения «статусной» информации о процессе, всё, что вам надо — прочесть файл `/proc/идентификатор-процесса/status`:

```
$ cat /proc/self/status
  Name:   cat
  State:  R (running)
  Tgid:   5452
  Pid:    5452
  PPid:   743
  TracerPid:      0                     (2.4)
  Uid:    501     501     501     501
  Gid:    100     100     100     100
  FDSize: 256
  Groups: 100 14 16
  VmPeak:     5004 kB
  VmSize:     5004 kB
  VmLck:         0 kB
  VmHWM:       476 kB
  VmRSS:       476 kB
  RssAnon:             352 kB
  RssFile:             120 kB
  RssShmem:              4 kB
  VmData:      156 kB
  VmStk:        88 kB
  VmExe:        68 kB
  VmLib:      1412 kB
  VmPTE:        20 kb
  VmSwap:        0 kB
  HugetlbPages:          0 kB
  Threads:        1
  SigQ:   0/28578
  SigPnd: 0000000000000000
  ShdPnd: 0000000000000000
  SigBlk: 0000000000000000
  SigIgn: 0000000000000000
  SigCgt: 0000000000000000
  CapInh: 00000000fffffeff
  CapPrm: 0000000000000000
  CapEff: 0000000000000000
  CapBnd: ffffffffffffffff
  Seccomp:        0
  voluntary_ctxt_switches:        0
  nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     1
```

строки в котором обозначают:

```
Table 1-2: Contents of the status files (as of 4.1)
..............................................................................
 Field                       Content
 Name                        filename of the executable
 State                       state (R is running, S is sleeping, D is sleeping
                             in an uninterruptible wait, Z is zombie,
                 T is traced or stopped)
 Tgid                        thread group ID
 Ngid                        NUMA group ID (0 if none)
 Pid                         process id
 PPid                        process id of the parent process
 TracerPid                   PID of process tracing this process (0 if not)
 Uid                         Real, effective, saved set, and  file system UIDs
 Gid                         Real, effective, saved set, and  file system GIDs
 FDSize                      number of file descriptor slots currently allocated
 Groups                      supplementary group list
 NStgid                      descendant namespace thread group ID hierarchy
 NSpid                       descendant namespace process ID hierarchy
 NSpgid                      descendant namespace process group ID hierarchy
 NSsid                       descendant namespace session ID hierarchy
 VmPeak                      peak virtual memory size
 VmSize                      total program size
 VmLck                       locked memory size
 VmHWM                       peak resident set size ("high water mark")
 VmRSS                       size of memory portions. It contains the three
                             following parts (VmRSS = RssAnon + RssFile + RssShmem)
 RssAnon                     size of resident anonymous memory
 RssFile                     size of resident file mappings
 RssShmem                    size of resident shmem memory (includes SysV shm,
                             mapping of tmpfs and shared anonymous mappings)
 VmData                      size of private data segments
 VmStk                       size of stack segments
 VmExe                       size of text segment
 VmLib                       size of shared library code
 VmPTE                       size of page table entries
 VmPMD                       size of second level page tables
 VmSwap                      amount of swap used by anonymous private data
                             (shmem swap usage is not included)
 HugetlbPages                size of hugetlb memory portions
 Threads                     number of threads
 SigQ                        number of signals queued/max. number for queue
 SigPnd                      bitmap of pending signals for the thread
 ShdPnd                      bitmap of shared pending signals for the process
 SigBlk                      bitmap of blocked signals
 SigIgn                      bitmap of ignored signals
 SigCgt                      bitmap of caught signals
 CapInh                      bitmap of inheritable capabilities
 CapPrm                      bitmap of permitted capabilities
 CapEff                      bitmap of effective capabilities
 CapBnd                      bitmap of capabilities bounding set
 Seccomp                     seccomp mode, like prctl(PR_GET_SECCOMP, ...)
 Cpus_allowed                mask of CPUs on which this process may run
 Cpus_allowed_list           Same as previous, but in "list format"
 Mems_allowed                mask of memory nodes allowed to this process
 Mems_allowed_list           Same as previous, but in "list format"
 voluntary_ctxt_switches     number of voluntary context switches
 nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches  number of non voluntary context switches
```

описание содержимого другого существенного файла — `/proc/идентификатор-процесса/stat`:

```
Table 1-4: Contents of the stat files (as of 2.6.30-rc7)
..............................................................................
 Field          Content
  pid           process id
  tcomm         filename of the executable
  state         state (R is running, S is sleeping, D is sleeping in an
                uninterruptible wait, Z is zombie, T is traced or stopped)
  ppid          process id of the parent process
  pgrp          pgrp of the process
  sid           session id
  tty_nr        tty the process uses
  tty_pgrp      pgrp of the tty
  flags         task flags
  min_flt       number of minor faults
  cmin_flt      number of minor faults with child's
  maj_flt       number of major faults
  cmaj_flt      number of major faults with child's
  utime         user mode jiffies
  stime         kernel mode jiffies
  cutime        user mode jiffies with child's
  cstime        kernel mode jiffies with child's
  priority      priority level
  nice          nice level
  num_threads   number of threads
  it_real_value (obsolete, always 0)
  start_time    time the process started after system boot
  vsize         virtual memory size
  rss           resident set memory size
  rsslim        current limit in bytes on the rss
  start_code    address above which program text can run
  end_code      address below which program text can run
  start_stack   address of the start of the main process stack
  esp           current value of ESP
  eip           current value of EIP
  pending       bitmap of pending signals
  blocked       bitmap of blocked signals
  sigign        bitmap of ignored signals
  sigcatch      bitmap of caught signals
  0     (place holder, used to be the wchan address, use /proc/PID/wchan instead)
  0             (place holder)
  0             (place holder)
  exit_signal   signal to send to parent thread on exit
  task_cpu      which CPU the task is scheduled on
  rt_priority   realtime priority
  policy        scheduling policy (man sched_setscheduler)
  blkio_ticks   time spent waiting for block IO
  gtime         guest time of the task in jiffies
  cgtime        guest time of the task children in jiffies
  start_data    address above which program data+bss is placed
  end_data      address below which program data+bss is placed
  start_brk     address above which program heap can be expanded with brk()
  arg_start     address above which program command line is placed
  arg_end       address below which program command line is placed
  env_start     address above which program environment is placed
  env_end       address below which program environment is placed
  exit_code     the thread's exit_code in the form reported by the waitpid system call
```

---

по поводу же того, какую именно информацию из псевдо-файловой системы `/proc` читают программы типа *ps*, и каким образом её интерпретируют, следует обратиться к исходным текстам этих конкретных программ.

---

доп. информация: [$ man 5 proc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Answer (score 1):

Для определения использования процессами ресурсов системы можно воспользоваться утилитами *ps*, *top* и *htop*. Эти утилиты считывают содержимое каталога `/proc` и выводят оттуда информацию в удобочитаемом виде на экран.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне нужно узнать именно о месте хранения данной информации. Это нужно для того, чтобы использовать ее в моем проекте (Системный монитор).